# JavaScript React bug: dropdown item stays open onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, toggle, state

I am trying to use a kebab dropdown menu, but it doesn't close once it's clicked a second time. It closes when you click anywhere outside, or when you select an item in the dropdown, but it doesn't close when you click on the actual icon that toggles it to open.

I am using the exact same code for another dropdown (different react component) right next to it, and that is working fine, so I'm not sure where the problem is coming from. I added an onFocus function, but that didn't seem to solve it either.

Please help me figure out what's going on.

I have the following code:

```
this.state = {
      isToolbarDropdownOpen: false,
      isToolbarKebabDropdownOpen: false,
    };

this.onToolbarDropdownToggle = isToolbarDropdownOpen => {
      this.setState({
        isToolbarDropdownOpen
      });
    };

    this.onToolbarKebabDropdownToggle = isToolbarKebabDropdownOpen => {
      this.setState({
        isToolbarKebabDropdownOpen
      });
    };

   this.onToolbarDropdownSelect = event => {
      this.setState({
        isToolbarDropdownOpen: !this.state.isToolbarDropdownOpen
      });
    };


    this.onToolbarKebabDropdownSelect = event => {
      this.setState({
        isToolbarKebabDropdownOpen: !this.state.isToolbarKebabDropdownOpen
      });
      this.onFocus();
    };

    this.onFocus = () => {
      const element = document.getElementById('toggle-id-6');
      element.focus();
    };
```

```
 /* this works! */
      <DataToolbarItem>
      <Dropdown
            onSelect={this.onToolbarDropdownSelect}
            position={DropdownPosition.right}
            toggle={<DropdownToggle onToggle={this.onToolbarDropdownToggle}>Creator</DropdownToggle>}
            isOpen={isToolbarDropdownOpen}
            dropdownItems={filterDropdownItems}
          />
      </DataToolbarItem>

 /* this doesn't work! */
      <DataToolbarItem>
        <Dropdown
          onSelect={this.onToolbarKebabDropdownSelect}
          toggle={<KebabToggle id="toggle-id-6" onToggle={this.onToolbarKebabDropdownToggle} />}
          isOpen={isToolbarKebabDropdownOpen}
          isPlain
          dropdownItems={toolbarKebabDropdownItems}
        />
```

Comment: Can you reproduce what you have so far in this CodePen [reactjs sandbox](https://codepen.io/pen?template=vvRRNg)?

Comment: @AndrewL64 Thanks. I've reproduced it here and it seems to be working in the sandbox but not in my project ... https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cerf-2yqx2

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working as it should in the codepen. In your project, are you getting any errors when you click the kebab dropdown menu button again?

Comment: @AndrewL64 I don't think so, no errors seem to be showing in the developer console on Chrome

Comment: It would be difficult to figure out the problem occuring in your server with the current code that you have provided tbh. You can try going through relevant parts of your code line by line and see if you missed something.